# Deploying a C# winform and MySQL project

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have developed a Windows-based project using C# and MySQL. Now I want to deploy this project to my client.

1. How to create an Installer (package)?
2. How to dump the database into the client's system?

Note:

- Applications will be installed across multiple systems -- each system has their own database
- System doesn't have MySQL installed (installation is not preferred).
- This is a completely standalone application, not related to any servers.

Problem: I cannot ask the end user to install MySQL in their system to be able to export, dump, and import in every system.

Required: A package installer which installs my project along with MySQL patches and required data in database.

Comment: Is the application deployed on multiple clients? Is the database supposed to be **shared** amongst those clients? If so, is MySQL installed on a server somewhere on the clients network? If not, is MySQL already installed on the client? As you can see, there are way too many unanswered questions - that's just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @SathishD: you said you "formatted code" -- why would you format something that isn't code as code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an installation package using install shield

Other alternatives

http://karcollection.blogspot.in/2012/05/mysql-silent-installation-in-windows.html

http://karcollection.blogspot.in/2012/05/mysql-silent-installation-in-windows.html

Comment: As u mentioned in the blog, it installs MySQL into the client System, Is there a way "so as my client can use my application without installing MySQL, along with MySQL services"?

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you used MySQL just because its a freely available database product?

by the sound of what your asking would SQL CE not be a better database option?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact

As far as i know with SQL CE you can embed the database into the application and would not need to install a database server on the client computer.

Comment: isn't there a way to use MySQL service without installing it. Since MySql is free I can install in N no. of systems, problem is For example: if i had used oracle(which isn't free), then I need to purchase those no. of license?

Comment: quick check on SO and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051686/how-to-run-mysql-on-windows-without-having-to-install